# How can I plot the graph to display the moving averages on the stock prices

Tags: python-3.x, analysis, datareader, python-ggplot

I am trying to plot a matplotlib graph to plot moving averages on the stock
prices, but it's not working.

I  have written the code but I kept getting error messages.

```
%matplotlib inline

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib import style

# Adjusting the size of matplotlib

import matplotlib as mpl

mpl.rc('figure', figsize=(8, 7))

mpl.__version__

# Adjusting the style of matplotlib

style.use('ggplot')

close_px.plot(label='T')

mavg.plot(label='mavg')

plt.legend()
```

I expected to see a graph of moving averages swinging around the actual stock

prices with the dates on the x-axis and frequency on the y-axis.

Thanks.

But I got the below error message:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-77-2fc08460da4d> in <module>

     10 # Adjusting the style of matplotlib

     11 style.use('ggplot')

---> 12 close_px.plot(label='T')

     13 mavg.plot(label='mavg')

     14 plt.legend()



----> 8 from pandas._libs.tslibs.frequencies import (

      9     FreqGroup, get_base_alias, get_freq, is_subperiod, is_superperiod)

     10 from pandas._libs.tslibs.period import Period

ImportError: cannot import name 'FreqGroup'
```

Comment: same problem here. pandas '0.22.0'

Comment: @ Dennis lyubyvyIy. It worked with the following line of codes:%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style



close_px.plot(label='T')
mavg.plot(label='mav